# Carrying a bicylce on a Saab 9-5

Tags: saab

I have a 2003 Saab 9-5. The car looks like this:

[image: Saab 9-5 2003]

I would like to be able to carry a small-ish bicycle now on regular occasions but unfortunately it cannot fit inside the car unless I take off one of the wheels.  As you can see the car has no roof rack or bars and it's not clear to me what you could attach to the back of the car to be able to carry a bicycle.

What is a cheap and effective way to fit the car to make it easy to carry a bicycle? I don't really know the first thing about this so please spell out exactly what I would need to buy if possible.

Answer (score 3):

The trunk mount bicycle racks are the cheapest.

You open your trunk and part of the device sits in there.  When you close your trunk it's 'mounted'.

They look like this.  They are -$40 on ebay.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am worried the lights and number plate will be obscured with this option. Also, do they work for bicycles without a cross bar (e.g. a ladies bicycle)?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work without a cross bar on the bicycle